# how dynamically initialize components of materialise design lite (google) for SPA?

Tags: material-design, materialize

how dynamically initialize components of materialise design lite (google) for SPA ? As I am dynamically initializing the components in a view the JS is not initializing. As i have tried with many solutions using componentHandler.

Answer (score 6):

To initialize the javascript components of MDL not starting to window.load you must update the DOM component:

componentHandler.upgradeDom();

For more information
https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/871

Comment: Yeah I have tried this one and also componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered() , but It seems some time its working fine but some time it doesn't. I need a permanent solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when the user clicks the back button. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: It works! but, now, my radios are crazy, I have 2 groups and the first is working but the second group takes the control of the first group, I mean... when I move one position in the first group, runs good, but if I move one radio of the second group, the same position in the first group moves too. :( [My english is not very good I know, I hope you understand me]